# If $a_n=n^2$, how to write down the first few terms of $a_{2^n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> If $a_n=n^2$, how to write down the first few terms of $a_{2^n}$?

Is it as simple as substituting $2^n$ for $n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is as simple as you said. You get $(2^{2n})$